# Allowing Optional Parameters for MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a search page that has multiple fields that are used to create a refined search. Every field is optional. I'm trying to start crafting my sql query so that it will work given the proper variables but I'm having trouble.

Here is the SQL query I currently have:

```
SELECT
  indicator.indid,
  indicator.indicator,
  indtype.indtype,
  provider.provider,
  report.report,
  actor.actor
FROM
  actor,
  indicator,
  indtype,
  report,
  provider
WHERE
  indicator.indtypeid = indtype.indtypeid
  AND indicator.actorid = actor.actorid
  AND indicator.reportid = report.reportid
  AND report.providerid = provider.providerid
  AND indicator.indicator LIKE '%$indicator%'
  AND indicator.indtypeid = $indtypeid;
```

Whenever I provide an `indicator` and an `indtypeid`, the search works just fine. However, when I leave the `indtypeid` field blank, and have the variable set to `*` (as its default value), the query returns no results. I've tried playing with the query manually and it doesn't seem to like the `*` or a `%` sign. Basically, if only an indicator is specified and no `indtypeid` is specified, I want to return all indicators for all `indtypeids`.

I'm sure I'm missing something minor, but I would appreciate any assistance that could be provided. I may be going about this all wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT i.indid,    i.indicator, it.indtype, 
       p.provider, r.report,    a.actor 
FROM actor a 
INNER JOIN indicator i ON a.actorid    = i.actorid
INNER JOIN indtype  it ON i.indtypeid  =  it.indtypeid
INNER JOIN report   r  ON i.reportid   = r.reportid 
INNER JOIN provider  p ON r.providerid = p.providerid 
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND ($indicator IS NULL OR i.indicator LIKE '%$indicator%')
  AND ($indtypeid IS NULL OR i.indtypeid = $indtypeid);
```

So if you pass a `$indicator = NULL`, then the first condition `AND ($indicator IS NULL OR i.indicator LIKE '%$indicator%')` will be ignored since it will resolve to `True`, and the same thing for the second condition.

I've removed other `Where` condition and replace them with `JOIN`s, and for `WHERE 1 = 1` to make the query work fine in case you pass the two variables `$indicator` and `$indtypeid` with `NULL` values for each, in this case it will return all results since `1 = 1` always true.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but when I throw it into my script it doesn't seem to work. It returns no results no matter what combination of attributes I utilize.

Comment: I tried to use this manually by removing the variable name and the NOT NULL check of the variable, just to see if I could get it working without the script, but still get no results.

SELECT i.indid, i.indicator, 
       it.indtype, p.provider, r.report, a.actor 
FROM actor a 
INNER JOIN indicator i ON a.actorid = i.actorid
INNER JOIN indtype  it ON i.indtypeid =  it.indtypeid
INNER JOIN report r    ON i.reportid = r.reportid 
INNER JOIN provider  p ON r.providerid = p.providerid 
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (i.indicator LIKE '%bad%')
  AND (i.indtypeid = '*');

Comment: @ChrisSanders, check your joins and thy relations between them, the query should work for just `Where 1 = 1` and should rerturn all data, otherwise there is a problem in your joins.

Comment: @ChrisSanders, What do you mean by `i.indtypeid = '*'` I think this is the problem becouse there is no rows in your tables that has `i.indtypeid = '*'`

Comment: By i.indtypeid = '*' I'm wanting to return all values for this. Just like I would do a SELECT * FROM xyz.

Comment: @ChrisSanders, I think it Won't work this way you can try it with `SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE Id = '*'`

Comment: That works just fine in the example, but  I'm still not having any luck with the actual code trying to be used in the app I'm working on.

Comment: @ChrisSanders, Update your question then with your actual code you are working on.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal you used 'dollar' sign for the parameter. Should not 'at' sign be used instead ?

Comment: @user3083339 I am not sure about the language the OP is using, I think it is PHP. Anyway, I used the same dollar sign he is using in the question.